# Implementing retry requests with Apache HttpClient5

Tags: java, http, keycloak

In case of temporary server unavailability / network outage I have to invoke an API call (Keycloak) several times.

With Apache HttpClient 4.X , I could do this:

```
 private HttpClient createHttpClient() {
        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy(3, true)) // 3 retries, retry even if request sent
                .build();
    }
    
    HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
```

How can I implement the same functionality using HttpClient5?

I could not find anything relevant in the documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77930336/175554 can give you a starting point, then you can generate your own list of filter exceptions.